# How to update a XACML / ALFA policy?

Tags: xacml, alfa

I have written policy in ALFA where:

- if the *amount to transfer* is **greater than** the *transfer limit*, then the request should be **denied**.

I wanted to know how to specify a particular transfer limit. And from an administrator point of view, if in future i want to update the transfer limit, where and how should it be done?

For eg .I want to set current transfer limit to *$2000*. How do I do that and then how do I update the transfer limit, if I want to?

Answer (score 1):

To add to what David mentioned, you could set this value in a database cell and update its value offline of ABA/XACML (using other processes in place in your org.). The value can then be queried at evaluation time by telling your PDP that `withdrawalLimit` is queried from a specific DB using the SQL "`select limit from ....`"

Comment: Since we are trying to move the PDP component from the IS to the end application,we have implemented the above solution in the end app.So now, our ESB pushes out the policy update to the Message Broker.The end apps are subscribed to the Message Broker. They consume the policy if it concerns them and then update their internal database. The end app then decides based on its db value whether to accept/reject the request.

Answer (score 0):

So, that is the advantage of XACML, As rules are defined in a policy, you can update the access control rules in dynamic manner.  Transfer limit may have been configured in your XACML policy. You can update it using the by editing the XACML policy. Then this update must be eserveredffected for the PDP runtime and request would be severed according to it.

`ALFA` plugin would have easy way of updating the XACML policy attributes rather than just updating the raw policy. Hope you may find it. But if you update the XACML policy,  it would also work.

Comment: I understand the dynamic update of rules in the policy. However what I don't get is how to update these policies. Would it be through the <Attribute Value> tag in the XACML policy or is there another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to see you are making progress. In your case, the authorization policy in ALFA would look as follows:

```
namespace com.axiomatics.banking{
    attribute actionId{
        category = actionCat
        id = "actionId"
        type = string
    }
    attribute resourceType{
        category = resourceCat
        id = "resourceType"
        type = string
    }
    attribute amount{
        category = resourceCat
        id = "amount"
        type = double
    }

    /**
     * Policy to transfer money
     */
    policy transferMoney{
        target clause actionId=="transfer" and resourceType=="money"
        apply firstApplicable
        /**
         * Deny access if amount is greater than 2000
         */
        rule checkAmount{
            target clause amount > 2000
            deny
        }
        /**
         * Grant access
         */
        rule allow{
            permit
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in my example I use a negative rule to deny access. This is great, for instance, if I want to add `Advice` or `Obligation` to that rule to indicate the reason for denial.

Now your question doesn't relate so much to the policy structure but rather to the values of the attributes. In XACML you have two options. Either:

- you "hard-code" the value into the policy, or
- you externalize the value and put it inside a policy information point (PIP) which could be a database, a web service, an LDAP... The benefit of externalizing the value is that you can now update the value without having to change the policy. The policy becomes more generic. Also it means you can have user-specific limits.

In the latter case, your rule becomes:

```
    /**
     * Deny access if amount is greater than the user's withdrawal limit
     */
    rule checkAmount{
        condition amount > withdrawalLimit
        deny
    }
```

In the Axiomatics Policy Server, you can configure a PIP / attribute connector to retrieve the value based on, say, the user id.

HTH,
David.